# Calculate the smallest possible value to measure the BAC angle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a right triangle acutangle and let $\overline{ AD}$, with D in $\overline{BC}$, be a height relative to point $A$. Let $Γ_1$
and $Γ_2$ as circumferences circumscribed to triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$, respectively. The circumference
$Γ_1$ crosses the $AC$ side at points $ A$ and $P$, while $Γ_2$ crosses the AB side at points $B$ and $Q$. Let
$X$ or line intersection point
BP with $Γ_2$ so that $P$ is between $B$ and $X$. Likewise, be $Y$ the intersection point of the line
$QC$ with $Γ_1$ so that $ Q $ is between $C$ and $Y$. Knowing that $A, X$ and $Y$
 are collinear, calculate the smallest possible value to measure the $\angle{BAC}$ angle.

I think triangular inequality would help

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inscribed in $ABC$ with the least perimeter is the triangle, called the *orthic triangle*, whose vertices are the feet of the three altitudes of $ABC$.

Comment: Sorry, but what does this imply?

Comment: I thought that this was what you wanted to know - "We want to find points M, N, and P on the sides BC, C A, and AB, respectively, such that the perimeter of MNP is minimal."

Comment: It was just an arbitrary idea to see if something came out of the problem. The real problem is calculating the possible Angle values

Comment: I think triangular inequality would help